# check if alert is clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document). ready(function() {
alert("clicked");
});
```

how to check if alert is clicked `OK`  using jquery . I know how to do using a prompt or confirmation

Comment: You mean alert() is closed or what? Alert method is modal so what are you looking for? Couldn't you just make some test?

Comment: Try confirm box:

$('#deleteBtn').click(function() {
  var didConfirm = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (didConfirm == true) {
    //delete here
  }
});

Comment: How can i change a tire using jQuery ? How can i build a nuclear reactor using jQuery ? How can i walk on water using jQuery ?

Comment: @Virus721 for water, i think you cannot. For the others, only a question of time, IMO...

Comment: @roasted: *everything* is possible when you have an appropriate jquery plugin.

Comment: @Virus721 you can do it... try some animations using jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put the code after the `alert` call:

```
$(document). ready(function() {
    alert("clicked");
    // code here is executed after the `alert` dialog was dismissed
});
```

This works because `alert` (just like `confirm` or `prompt`) *blocks* the JS execution.

You cannot distinguish though whether `OK` was clicked or the dialog was just closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document). ready(function() {
    alert("clicked"); //first ok 
    alert("click has been detected") //alert to detect the first ok
});
```